# Derivative of the Lagrangian dual: Can I treat the optimal parameter $x^*$ in the dual $g(\lambda) = L(x^*, \lambda)$ as a constant w.r.t $\lambda$?

Tags: convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Suppose I have a standard constrained optimization problem
$$
\min_x f(x) \quad \text{s.t.} h_i(x) \ge 0,
$$
where $f$ and $h_1,...,h_m$ are convex functions $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. The dual is given as
$$
g(\lambda) = \min_xL(x, \lambda) = L(x^*, \lambda)
$$
with $L$ the Lagrangian. To obtain the optimal Lagrangian multipliers, I need to solve
$$
\lambda^* = \text{argmax}_\lambda \;g(\lambda).
$$
I would go on and take the derivative w.r.t $\lambda$. My question is now:

**Can I treat the optimal parameter $x^*$ in the dual $g(\lambda) = L(x^*, \lambda)$ as a constant w.r.t $\lambda$?**

On my first thought: No, since it depends on $\lambda$. (If it didn't we would already have solved the primal problem). But I have found several examples, where we can take the derivative without the substitution of $x^*$ and treat it as a constant. So I was wondering if that is a general rule. If that is somehow true, this would simplify the derivative a lot.

I'll give a concrete example:
Let's solve
$$
\min x^2 \quad \text{s.t.} -x -2 \le 0
$$
The resulting Lagrangian is $ L(x, \lambda) = x^2 + \lambda(-x -2)$.
Taking the derivative w.r.t $x$, and setting it to 0 yields
$ 2x - \lambda = 0 \implies x^* = \lambda / 2$.

The dual is therefore
$$
g(\lambda) = x^{*2} + \lambda(-x^* -2) = \frac 1 4 \lambda^2 + \lambda(-\frac \lambda 2 -2).
$$
Now, when i take the "correct" derivative by taking the derivative of the right side w.r.t. to $\lambda$, I'll get
$$
g'(\lambda) = - \frac \lambda 2 - 2.
$$
This is the same as if I take $x^{*}$ as a constant on the left side and take the derivative, resulting in $$-x^* - 2 = - \frac \lambda 2 - 2.$$

Why does this work?
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: $x^*$ depends on $\lambda$, could you share one of the several examples you found that shows otherwise?

Comment: You can have a look at the example below. After some chain/quotient ruling you find that the derivative is the same as when I just take x* as a constant.

Comment: @LinAlg I've edited the question to give a concrete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the Lagrangian is
$$L(x,\lambda) = f(x) - \sum_i \lambda_i h_i(x).$$
and $x^*$ satisfies $f'(x^*) - \sum_i \lambda_i h_i'(x^*) = 0$. Assume $x(\lambda)$ is a function that satisfies that equation for all $\lambda$, then
$$g(\lambda) = f(x(\lambda)) - \sum_i \lambda_i h_i(x(\lambda)).$$

By application of the chain rule and the product rule:
\begin{align}
g'(\lambda) &= f'(x(\lambda))x'(\lambda) -\sum_i h_i(x(\lambda))- \sum_i \lambda_i h_i'(x(\lambda))x'(\lambda) \\
&= \left( f'(x(\lambda)) -\sum_i \lambda_i h_i'(x(\lambda)) \right)x'(\lambda) - \sum_i h_i(x(\lambda)) \\
&=  - \sum_i h_i(x(\lambda)),
\end{align}
which is what you get if take the derivative of $g$ without applying the chain rule and plug in $x(\lambda)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! This decreases the complexity of some derivatives by a lot. And very handy proof.

Comment: @PhilippD. just make sure $x'(\lambda)$ exists :)

Comment: One correction: the final derivative should be
$$
\frac {\partial g}{\partial \lambda_i} = - h_i(x(\lambda))
$$
The sum is not present anymore and the general derivative should be a vector, since $g: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no, $x^*$ is not a constant and you cannot differentiate the Lagrangian as if it were.

Consider the Lagrangian $L(x, \lambda) = x^2 + 1 + \lambda(x-2)(x-4)$. If you take the infimum over $x$ by taking $\partial L /\partial \lambda$ and setting it to zero, you'll find $x^* = 3\lambda/(\lambda + 1)$. Clearly $x^*$ depends on $\lambda$ so you must use the chain rule to differentiate $L$ w.r.t. $\lambda$.

Comment: I looked into your example: If i take the derivative of the dual and treat x* as a constant I get to the same result of the derivative as if I replaced x* with 3 \lambda / (\lambda + 1)! My final derivative is

(- lambda^3 -  3 lambda^2 + 6 lambda + 8) / (lambda + 1)^3

in both cases. So this would be an example where my theory works.

Comment: @PhilippD. Maybe I'm confused what your approach is. You propose that the dual is $g(\lambda) = L(x^*, \lambda) = (x^*)^2 + 1 + \lambda(x^*-2)(x^*-4)$, then to take the derivative of the dual with respect to lambda as if $x^*$ was a constant having no dependence on $\lambda$ to get $g'(\lambda) = (x^*-2)(x^*-4)$? 


If I sub in $x^* = 3\lambda/(\lambda +1)$ to this I get $-(\lambda - 2)(\lambda + 4)/(\lambda +1)^2$. I haven't checked thoroughly but this does not seem equivalent to the rational you wrote above

Comment: It is the same solution you got, it is just expanded with the factor $(\lambda +1)$ (so pardon on my side that I didn't use a shortened version of the derivative):
$
\frac {-(\lambda - 2)(\lambda + 4)}{(\lambda + 1)^2} = \frac {(- \lambda^2 - 2\lambda + 8)(\lambda + 1)}{(\lambda + 1)^3} = \frac {-\lambda³ - 3 \lambda^2 + 6 \lambda + 8}{(\lambda + 1)^3}
$

Comment: I had the expanded version since the more complicated way with the chain rule got me that result first. If you want I can give you another example where this seems to work.

Comment: You are actually right. This will definitely always happen in the 1 variable case. If the Lagrangian is $L(x, \lambda) = f_0(x)+\lambda f_1(x)$ then infimum is found by setting the derivative wrt $x$ to 0. $\partial L/\partial x = f'_0(x)+\lambda f'_1(x) = 0$. If you take the derivative of $L$ with respect to $\lambda$ at the optimal $x^*(\lambda)$, you get $(f'_0(x^*) + \lambda f'_1(x^*))(dx^*/d\lambda) + f_1(x^*)$. The first part is clearly zero from infimum calculation. Would need to think more about multiple variable case